# Should the solar-power tag be changed to solar?

Tags: discussion

There don't seem to be any yet, but eventually I would expect questions around both solar-based electricity (e.g. photovoltaics) and solar thermal (e.g. hot water and solar ovens). Do we want to have separate 'solar-power' and 'solar-thermal' tags, or a combined 'solar' tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd have thought: neither [solar-power](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-power) nor [solar](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar).

[solar-thermal](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-thermal) and [photovoltaics](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photovoltaics) would seem to have it covered, between them.

[solar-electric](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-electric) should be a synonym for [photovoltaics](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photovoltaics)

Solar cooking, and solar cooling via absorption chillers, both use solar-thermal.

Comment: I agree with that distinction - I just wonder whether people coming to ask questions will know to look for a photovoltaics tag rather than one with 'solar' in it.

Comment: good point - updated